# Traffic on Adsense Dashboard and Blogspot Dashboard differs

Tags: blogger, adsense, blogspot

I have a blogspot blog which was accepted by Google for Adsense:
http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.com

The statistic reports a typical traffic around 100 visits a day:

[image]

The Adsense report shows only one visit a day:

[image]

If I open my blog I see, that Ads are shown correctly:

[image]
Any idea what is wrong here?

Many thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. I've not authorised all Websites for Adsense. Looks like there is a difference between WWW.Websitename and http://Websitename.

After allowing all Websites the numbers are as expected